# Classpath resource within jar

Tags: java, jar, classpath, resources

I have a project A, which contains some java files and a classpath resource R.txt. Within the project I use ClassLoader.getSystemResource("R.txt"); to retrieve R.txt.

Then I have a project B which includes project A's jar-file. Now getSystemResource("R.txt") wont find the textfile (and yes, it's still in the root of the jar file). Even trying "/R.txt" as was suggested on some other site didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use `getResource` instead of `getSystemResource` to use a resource specific to a given classloader instead of the system. For example, try any of the following:

```
URL resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("R.txt");
URL resource = Foo.class.getClassLoader().getResource("R.txt");
URL resource = getClass().getResource("/R.txt");
URL resource = Foo.class.getResource("/R.txt");
```

Note the leading slash when calling [`Class.getResource`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) instead of [`ClassLoader.getResource`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)); `Class.getResource` is relative to the package containing the class unless you have a leading slash, whereas `ClassLoader.getResource` is always absolute.

Comment: Amazing. This completely solved my problem. Thanks for the superfast input 

// Johan

Comment: One more related question: we may get InputStream from this URL resources, but how could we create a **File** object from the returned URL object. I tried to create a **URI** object with the "URLObject.toURI()", and use this URI object to create a file, unfortunately, it throws an "URI is not hierarchical exception". Could you give me some help ? Thanks a lot .

Comment: @EnsomHodder: Um, not sure - but not all resources *are* files - in particular, it won't be if it's in a jar file.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of when the `/` is needed.

Comment: @Jeff: I've rolled back the edit because `Class.ClassLoader` isn't a classname. The method is in the `ClassLoader` class. Yes, you often *call* `Class.getClassLoader()` to get a classloader, but the call is still `ClassLoader.getResource`...

Answer (score 5):

Apparently your JAR is not loaded by the system classloader, so `getSystemResource()` can't work. This should work:

```
ClassFromProjectA.class.getClassLoader().getResource("R.txt")
```

IMO more convenient is putting resources inside the same package as the classes that use them, so you can use the shorter

```
ClassFromProjectA.class.getResource("R.txt")
```

(or, inside that class just `getClass().getResource("R.txt")`)

Answer (score 2):

Does [ClassLoader.getResource()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) work ? At the moment you're simply specifying that the system classloader is to be used.

Comment: Works like a charm. Just had to use the correct classloader :)