# Java: Loading resources from the file system

Tags: java, file-io, resources

**My Project Setup**

I have the following project setup:

```
\program.jar  
\images\logo.png
```

In my code, I reference the image with the relative URL `"images/logo.png"`.

**Problem**

If I run this program with the following command while in the directory:

```
c:\projects\program_dir\bin\>java -jar program.jar
```

Then everything works and Java is able to locate the image.

Now, my problem is, that I need to be able to run the program from a different directory.

```
c:\>java -jar c:\projects\program_dir\bin\program.jar
```

The program is executed, but now all the relative URLs no longer work.

**What I need**

How do I calculate the execution home of the program.jar file, so that I can change my relative URLs into absolute URLs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I would do, if possible, is package your images in with your Jar.

That way you don't have to worry about where your Jar is launched from.

You would then need to load images similar to the following:

```
InputStream stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().
                                     getResourceAsStream("/images/logo.png");
```

Comment: +1 Leverage classpath for loading static resources. 

See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861500/url-to-load-resources-from-the-classpath-in-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294196/load-resource-from-anywhere-in-classpath, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900154/classpath-resource-within-jar

Answer (score 1):

You should really include your resources in your JAR.

Failing that, you can parse the absolute path out of the Main class resource. Assuming your Main class is actually called "Main":

```
Main.class.getResource("Main.class").getPath();
```

Answer (score 0):

Resources have to be in the class path(s). You may try one of these:

1. Placing the images into the `program.jar`.
2. Like most of the programs, they have a `APP_HOME` directory, e.g. `MAVEN_HOME`, register that and refer to your files as `File` instead - `$APP_HOME/the-file.ext` (with `System.getenv()`).

Answer (score 0):

As Nelson mentioned, package them with your JAR (just copy them alongside your .class files), then you can find them via a simple `this.getClass().getClassLoder().getResource("images/foo.png")`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a parameter which describes your class path. Should look something like

```
java -cp c:\projects\program_dir\bin -jar program.jar
```

this will put your jar and image on the class path and it will load successfully.

Comment: This is actually false ([java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html)):

`-jar When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.`