# How to load any file present under the conf or resources directory in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I am asking a very naive and newbie question.

Can anybody please tell me the correct way to load a file present under the src/conf or src/resources directory into my Java class using Spring.

Comment: what do you mean by loading file ?//

Comment: I want to load the file as a resource , and pass the path of the resource as a param

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309022/java-loading-resources-from-the-file-system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spring way would be using the `ResourceLoader`.

@See [Spring Reference - Chapter 4.4 The ResourceLoader](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-resourceloader)