# how to read text file relative path

Tags: java, path, relative-path

I have read sources here & there, but did not get the following code working. Basically, I wish to read a text file, named 'Administrator' from the folder 'src'. I will need a relative path, since this project may be transferred to another person. Please be patient with me.

```
public void staffExists () throws IOException
    {               
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788080/reading-a-text-file-in-java
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream ("/DBTextFiles/Administrator.txt")));

        try
        {               
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!(line.startsWith("*")))
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }               

        finally
        {
            reader.close();
        }           
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read text file from relative path in a project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844307/how-to-read-text-file-from-relative-path-in-a-project)

Comment: @Dooby Inc: have looked at the suggested url. but I cannot get it working still, please kindly guide me.

Comment: @ Little Child: I got this persistent error io.filenotfoundexception

Comment: The first line under the method signature should go inside the try block, nothing else in there cause throws an exception.

Comment: Use double slashes in path specification. "//DBTextFiles//Administrator.txt"

Comment: wats the exception you facinf

Comment: @Little Child , Please make sure your application have Read access to the Directory or to the file , And Your file path is possibly invalid that's why you are getting a FileNotFound  exception ,

Comment: @DjDexter5GHz double slashes is not the correct syntax for a relative file path... in fact I don't know what it would be correct for in Java, probably nothing.

Comment: @DoobyInc LOL ! I am not the OP here :D

Comment: yeah, i just googled that, and you are right. I had similar problems like this guy, but i forgot how to solve it. I think this below should do the trick. :)

Comment: @little child , Sorry for the mistake buddy

Comment: Now i get more confused with the many answers. which approach do I take then?

Comment: Just wrote a solution here, hope it helps 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638582/java-relative-file-paths

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a valid absolute path (on the systems I'm aware of):

```
    /path/to/directory/../../otherfolder/etc/
```

So what the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844307/how-to-read-text-file-from-relative-path-in-a-project) was saying, was to get the path to the current directory with:

```
    String filePath = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
```

Then concatenate your relative path with:

```
    filePath.concat("path to the property file");
```

Answer (score 11):

Now I get it, somewhat answers here & there do help in getting me to the goal. Did a short edit to my code & it worked. Hope it'll also help some poor souls out there.

```
String filePath = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
System.out.println (filePath);

//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788080/reading-a-text-file-in-java    
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874066/how-to-read-text-file-relative-path
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath + "/src/DBTextFiles/Administrator.txt"));

try
{                           
    String line = null;         
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if (!(line.startsWith("*")))
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }               
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}               

finally
{
    reader.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct:

```
new FileReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream ("/DBTextFiles/Administrator.txt"))
```

You want:

```
new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream ("/DBTextFiles/Administrator.txt"))
```

Comment: It would be nice to explain why it's not correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In almost all cases you should use the portable forward slash `"/"."` In every case you should use either the File constructor that accepts a File (parent) & String (file name) or use `System.getProperty("file.separator").`