# How to read a file that is located in the project folder java

Tags: java, io, filepath, filereader, filenotfoundexception

Using eclipse, I have a file titled bad_words.txt in my project folder titled HackGSU. I want locate the file and read the contents of the file. I saw this answer [how to read text file relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874066/how-to-read-text-file-relative-path) and I tried this:

```
private static String words[][] = new String[3][];
private static int ok = 17 + 2; //Add two for comment & empty line in text file
private static int med = 26 + 2; //Add two for comment & empty line in text file
private static int bad = 430 + 1; //Add one for comment in text file
private static String p = new File("").getAbsolutePath();

public static String[][] openFile() {

    p.concat("/HackGSU/bad_words.txt");

    //Set the a limit for the amount of words in each row
    words[0] = new String[getOk()];
    words[1] = new String[getMed()];
    words[2] = new String[getBad()];

    //Read the text file to add bad words to an array
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(p);
        //Wrap file
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        //Add each line of file into the words array
        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {             

            for(int j = 0; j < words[i].length; j++) {
                try {
                    words[i][j] = br.readLine();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    return words;
}
```

But I received this traceback:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\nbrow_000\workspaceProjects\HackGSU (Access is denied)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at gsu.hack.harassment.BadWords.openFile(BadWords.java:28)
at gsu.hack.harassment.HarassFilter.<clinit>(HarassFilter.java:10)
at gsu.hack.harassment.CheckPercentage.main(CheckPercentage.java:20)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at gsu.hack.harassment.HarassFilter.checkHarass(HarassFilter.java:23)
at gsu.hack.harassment.CheckPercentage.main(CheckPercentage.java:20)
```

I also so this answer [How to read a text file directly from Internet using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259339/how-to-read-a-text-file-directly-from-internet-using-java), but I had a problem with the URL constructor.

If I put the local file path (C://.../bad_words.txt) it works just fine, but how can I get the program to read the file so that if I package the software it will still find the proper file path.

Comment: change to `HackGSU/bad_words.txt`

Comment: Is `HackGSU` the project's folder ? or a sub folder in it ?

Comment: `p.concat("/HackGSU/bad_words.txt")` won't work as you might except. Strings are immutable. `concat` does not add something to `p` but returns a new String. Change to `p+="/HackGSU/bad_words.txt"`

Comment: @c0der its the projects folder. I realized that I had to drop "/HackGSU" from the file path

Comment: @MadMatts yeah that was a problem, I also had to change the file path too

Comment: Indeed. You can answer your own question. Also next time consider an [MCVE]. No need for so much code for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the error it doesn't look like you are getting the full path. Instead of

```
p.concat("/HackGSU/bad_words.txt");
```

Try

```
p = p.concat("/HackGSU/bad_words.txt");
```

Comment: The "/HackGSU" part was a problem because I already had the folder. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your resource is already in the classpath, you don't need to make use of relative paths with the `File` class. You can easily obtain it from the classpath like:

```
java.net.URL url = getClass().getResource("bad_words.txt");
File file = new File(url.getPath());
```

or even directly to an inputstream:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("bad_words.txt");
```

Since you have a `static` method use:

```
InputStream in = YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("bad_words.txt");
```

Furthermore, as I mentioned it already in my comment:

```
p.concat("/HackGSU/bad_words.txt");
```

does not concat to `p` but returns a new concatenated String, because Strings are immutable.
Simply use: `p+="/HackGSU/bad_words.txt"` instead

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use backslash instead of slash:

```
p.concat("\HackGSU\bad_words.txt");
```

You can also try to type double backslash:

```
p.concat("\\HackGSU\\bad_words.txt");
```

Comment: `concat` only won't change a thing in the outcome, because Strings are immutable, you need a new assignment back to p