# Relative path difficulties

Tags: java, path, processing

I started working with some files, something easy.

I read that the `File` class support relative paths, so I tried something like:

```
File file_bg = new File("data\\bg.png");
if(file_bg.exists())
  flag_bg = true;
```

Ok, now, making some debugging I noticed that every File variable have as parent path the same path where the IDE is, instead of the path where my project is.

Is it a common behavior or I have to set up something before starting the sketch?
Is it equal for java IDEs like NetBeans?

One more question, there is a way to keep a `String` variable in memory that contains the path of my `.pde` file?

Thanks a lot for the interest, waiting a response!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844307/how-to-read-text-file-from-relative-path-in-a-project, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638582/java-relative-file-paths

Comment: In Windows anyway, the *current directory* is set at the process level.  In other words, this has nothing to do with the IDE.  The runtime asks the operating system what the current path is.  Not sure if this is a helpful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to store a string with that directory, Processing can give it to you with `sketchPath()` and `dataPath()`... Not particularly odd, google's first result for "processing sketch path" returns [this](http://processing.org/discourse/beta/num_1229443269.html)

thus:

```
File file_bg = new File(dataPath("bg.png"));
```

Comment: `dataPath("")` paradoxically doesn't return the data folder of the sketch, but a folder [`null\data\ `] inside the IDE folder.

Comment: how about sketchPath()? What version of Processing are you using?

Comment: also try this hacky slashy method: `args[0].split("=")[1]`

Comment: I am using the last version, `2.1.1`.
`sketchPath()` returns the same path of `dataPath()` without entering in `data\ `.
By now I set the drive folder [is an external hd] with `getAbsolutePath().getChar(0) + ":\\";` and then I add the ret of the path statically.