# File not found exception while reading the from jar in spring?

Tags: java, spring

I am working on spring ,I want to read file name from a jar file,But I am getting `FileNotFoundException`. Any one help me, please check my code below.

```
 ClassPathResource classPathResource =  new ClassPathResource("test.txt");
   System.out.println(classPathResource.getPath());
    System.out.println(classPathResource.getURI());
    System.out.println(classPathResource.getURL().getPath());
    System.out.println(classPathResource.getURI().getPath());
```

but when I wrote like below

```
System.out.println(classPathResource.getFile().getCanonicalPath());
System.out.println(classPathResource.getFile().getPath());
```

the above two lines are throwing exception, but when I am working with normal java program, everything is working great.

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900154/classpath-resource-within-jar) help?

Comment: Maybe check where the file is put when you package your program.

Comment: What is "normal java program" ?