# Java program that worked in Eclipse fails when in a Jar

Tags: java

The following line of code:

```
SoyFileSet sfs = sfsBuilder.add(this.getClass().getResource("templates/mail.soy")).build();
```

works when run outside of a Jar but fails with a null pointer exception. Similar posts indicate that I should try getResourceAsStream but the add method wants a URL. So I think I have to convert the Stream to a URL but it is not clear to me exactly how to proceed.

Comment: What is the structure of your project? Maybe you need to start from location of resources like `/templates/mail.soy`

Comment: Use the ClassLoader getResource() instead.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1900173/16549

Comment: Include the templates directory in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

sfsBuilder.add() also allows you to add content as CharSequence.
So, you can read the file yourself and add it to the builder.

Something like:

```
SoyFileSet sfs = SoyFileSet.builder().add(IOUtils.toString(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("templates/mail.soy")), "file/path/for/messages").build();
```

IOUtils is from apache's commons-io project

Comment: This does not seem to compile.

Comment: Response updated. That method also requires a filePath for messages. https://closure-templates.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc-lite/com/google/template/soy/SoyFileSet.Builder.html

Comment: what are the messages? is it output directory or should it be non-empty when I start?

Comment: This is still failing. I have tried templates with a leading slash and without but am getting an Unknown source error which I think has to do with IOUtils not finding mail.soy.

Answer (score 0):

By the code you have posted, I guess `templates/mail.soy` is a file which belongs to your project, so it should be properly *packed into* the jar. However, the path should begin with a slash: `/templates/mail.soy` will match the following jar structure:

```
META-INF/
templates/
    mail.soy
mypackage/
    MyProgram.class
```

Answer (score 0):

This finally worked as follows:

{SoyFileSet sfs = sfsBuilder.add(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/templates/email.soy")).build();}

Not sure if this matters but in Eclipse the Runnable Jar was created using Package Required Libraries...